# Paste clipboard in cell same range as source

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks with the same data structure. One is a spreadsheet used to store data, and the other is a data capture spreadsheet. The latter is sent out and filled in, and then I need to copy over the data to the storage sheet.

In both sheets, there are protected cells that contain categorical formulas, which I want to ignore.

This is the data structure:

| ID | NAME | DP1 | DP2 | PROTECT1 | DP3 | DP4 | PROTECT2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | One | A | 10 | YELLOW | G | 5 | RED |
| 2 | Two | B | 20 | GREEN | F | 10 | ORANGE |
| 3 | Three | C | 30 | BLUE | E | 15 | PINK |

I handle the copy from one sheet using:

```
  Sub HighlightCell()
  Dim rng As Range
  With ActiveSheet
      Set rng = Union(Range("A3:B100"),.Range("C3:D100"),.Range("F3:G100"))
  End With
  rng.Select
  End Sub
```

When I paste, I want the clipboard to fill the same ranges as source.

Is this possible with VBA?

Comment: As your range is dis-contiguous, you will need to write a loop, which copies a distinct contiguous range in each iteration.